# GridView with multi-selection does not display selected item state (only pressed state)

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-selector

I have a `GridView` which has a ChoiceMode of `GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`.  I'd like the selection to behave similarly to what you would see in the Gallery app (ie. long-press on an item, selected item has a semi-transparent foreground color to indicate it's selected, short-press on other items adds or removes them from the selection).

I've created a state selector like so:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

Here is the `pressed_background.xml` file:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@color/pressed" />
</shape>
```

And the color it refers to:

```
<color name="pressed">#CC30d3dc</color>
```

I'm applying it to my grid like so:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:columnWidth="112dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selectable_background"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

And here is the `XML` for the grid item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/add_photos_image_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/add_photos_image_size"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the selected state never appears on the grid item.  When I start to long press, the pressed state color appears as expected on top of the grid item, but as soon as it becomes selected, the color disappears and there is no indication that the item is in a selected state.  The contextual action bar appears as expected.  I've tried as many different variations of the `<selector>` and the grid item background as I could think of.

Comment: Was this issue actually solved?